# How to pass a variable value from javascript to perl

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, perl, cgi

I'm using a JavaScript plugin to get the IP address. If the IP address starts with `10.15` I want to assign one value to a variable, and if the IP starts with `10.13` I want to assign a different value to the same variable.(I don't know if the variable has to be in Perl or JavaScript)

I'm trying this but is not working.

```
my $propt = "";
    getUserIP(function(ip) { 
        console.log('IP: ' + ip);  
        const ips = ip.split('.');

        var pro = document.getElementById('property');
        console.log(pro);
        if (ips[0] === "10" && ips[1] === "15")  {
          pro.value = "propt1";
    To_Here
      $propt = "SRC";
    print <<"To_Here";      
        }
        else if(ips[0] === "10" && ips[1] === "13") {
            pro.value = "propt2";
    To_Here
      $propt = "ACC";
    print <<"To_Here"; 
        }  
        else {
            pro.value = "propt";
    To_Here
      $propt = "TAP";
    print <<"To_Here"; 
        }  
        console.log(pro);
```

First I tried passing the value to an HTML input and reading the value of the input but I don't know if this is possible in Perl

```
<input id="property" type="hidden" name="property" value=""/>
```

The final step of what I'm trying to do is to run a query based on the property

```
$ql = "Select from properties where property = '?????' <----
```

Comment: Perl cannot "see" anything from JavaScript unless you make an XMLHttpRequest / XHR / Ajax call back to it. Why not just do it all in Perl? Every web server has the ability to retrieve the remote address from the request.

Comment: Is that supposed to be Perl code with embedded here docs containing JavaScript? Aren't there missing initial `print <<"To_Here"` and ending `print <<"To_Here` statements? And shouldn't `To_Here` be flush to the left margin? Or am I misunderstanding you completely?

Comment: Conventionally, Perl runs on the server system and JavaScript runs in the client browser. To pass the information in a hidden input field back to the server you would need to submit the form.

Comment: Please identify this "JavaScript plugin" so that we can better guess what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

On the JavaScript side you will need to send a GET request to the Perl script. I've only done this using jQuery (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) so you'll need to adapt this if you want a pure JavaScript solution:

```
function getUserIp(ips) {

    var ipString = ips.join(';');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/path/to/script.pl',
        data: { user_ips : ipString },
        statusCode: {
            200: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#id').html(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note that the `ips` variable should be a string when you pass it to Perl. You can pass an array of params to Perl (see [CGI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Fetching-the-names-of-all-the-parameters-passed-to-your-script)), but I've found splitting a string after the fact to be the most reliable.

I'll show how to capture the parameter using Perl CGI because its simple, but if you're planning on making a full website then I strongly recommend using a web framework. There are several for Perl, like [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) and [Mojolicious](https://mojolicious.org/), with varying learning curves.

Using Perl's CGI module, you can capture parameters using the aptly-named `param()` method:

```
#! perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); # just to make it easier to see errors

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $ip_string = $cgi->param('user_ips');

my @ips = split(';', $ip_string);

my $results;
foreach my $ip (@ips) {
    # do whatever here to populate $results
}

# send results back to jQuery
print $cgi->header( -type => 'text/plain', -status => '200' );
print $results;
print $cgi->end_html;

1;
```

Make sure you add the appropriate header that corresponds to the `statusCode` in the `$.ajax()` method and also call `end_html()` at the end of the Perl script, otherwise the jQuery/JavaScript may not understand/capture the results.